# Gradle in Batch file prevents cmd.exe from exiting

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have a batch script that does something like this:

```
call gradle clean shadowJar
exit
```

The `exit` command doesn't seem to work, however. The command prompt window will stay alive even after the gradle job is done. Removing the `gradle` call allows the window to close after the batch script is done, so is this because of the `gradle` build job after all? If yes, then is there a way to get the command window to close after running the `gradle` job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause. Gradle created a Gradle Daemon for the build process, which lives even after the build job has completed. Running `gradle clean shadowJar --no-daemon` allows the command prompt window to close.